# python pandas : decimal point after integer?

Tags: python, pandas, integer, decimal

I'm going through the Pandas tutorial, and came across something I haven't seen before. There is a decimal point after the integer.

Here's a gist with the link to the tutorial: https://gist.github.com/findjashua/82717d2f3261a92ce528

What is the purpose of the decimal point after the integer?.

Comment: Look at the dtype of the series: including the decimal point makes it a float.

Comment: Float vs Int. No particular reason in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it just makes it `float` instead of `int` as shown below:

```
In [1]: type(5)
Out[1]: int

In [2]: type(5.)
Out[2]: float
```